# How to group_concat only duplicates?

Tags: mysql

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| First | apple |
| First | banana |
| Second | apple |
| Second | banana |
| Second | orange |
| Third | apple |
| Third | banana |

Result should be

| name | duplicate_values |
| --- | --- |
| First | apple, banana |
| Second | apple, banana |
| Third | apple, banana |

Is it possible to do it in one query without subqueries?

Comment: What if there is no intersection (e.g. `Second` only has `orange`)? And why don't you like subqueries?

Comment: because I want to make most optimized query

Comment: when we do 2 queries sql server accesses to datatable two times right? Why we cant work with 1 select result?

Comment: if there is no intersection, then do not show value

Comment: Do you want to return only the values that repeat for every name (as your example seems to imply) or are you looking for any duplicates (any values that occur at least twice in the table)?

Comment: What should happen if I add (Fourth, orange), (Fifth, apple, orange), (Sixth, banana, orange) ?

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that a **value** may only be included in the output if it is encountered as many times as there are distinct **name**s in the dataset.  Therefore, the logical steps that need to be performed are:

1. Count the distinct names.
2. Count each value.
3. Filter out the values that occur fewer times than the number of distinct names.
4. Aggregate the remaining ones.

All this is probably impossible to achieve with a single SELECT without *any* nesting.  It should theoretically be possible to produce the desired result without hitting the table twice if you allow nesting in the form of a *derived table*, like this:

```
SELECT
  name
, GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY value ASC) AS duplicate_values
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *
    , COUNT(name) OVER (PARTITION BY value) AS name_count_per_value
    , COUNT(DISTINCT name) OVER () AS distinct_name_count
    FROM
      YourTable
  ) AS s
WHERE
  name_count_per_value = distinct_name_count
GROUP BY
  name
;
```

Logically, the table is only accessed once in this case.  Although internal implementation might cause the engine to refer to the table more than once, that would likely be out of your control, so I would consider this to be a single-pass solution, from the logical standpoint at least.

In any event, the more important issue here is that, although window functions have been supported since version 8.0, MySQL is yet to add support for window aggregate functions *that use `DISTINCT`*.  The above query will therefore produce the following error if you try to run it in MySQL 8:

> `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support '<window function>(DISTINCT ..)'`

The easiest and cleanest way I can see to work around this is using a subquery:

```
SELECT
  name
, GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY value ASC) AS duplicate_values
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *
    , COUNT(name) OVER (PARTITION BY value) AS name_count_per_value
    FROM
      YourTable
  ) AS s
WHERE
  name_count_per_value = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name) FROM YourTable)
GROUP BY
  name
;
```

In the above query, the second nested SELECT

(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name) FROM YourTable)

is a proper subquery, and you can see that the entire statement now references the table twice.  That usually translates to actually accessing the table twice by the engine.  You can see how avoiding a subquery in your case appears to be a difficult problem.

That being said, there *is* a workaround to the above mentioned limitation of using a window version of `COUNT(DISTINCT)`, although it might result in a query plan that would be little better than a plan generated from actually referencing the table twice.  Anyway, the idea is to use two `DENSE_RANK` calls like this:

```
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name DESC)
+ DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name ASC)
- 1
```

The result of this expression will be a value that is constant across all rows and equal exactly to the number of distinct occurrences of `name`, provided that `name` has no nulls.

Therefore, we can take the first query and redefine `distinct_name_count` using the expression shown above:

```
SELECT
  name
, GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY value ASC) AS duplicate_values
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *
    , COUNT(name) OVER (PARTITION BY value) AS name_count_per_value
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name DESC)
    + DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name ASC) - 1 AS distinct_name_count
    FROM
      YourTable
  ) AS s
WHERE
  name_count_per_value = distinct_name_count
GROUP BY
  name
;
```

A live version of the queries in this answer can be found in [this db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3f88941b4de1691c42f1bcbb7aeef163).

In conclusion I would like to emphasise what I have already mentioned in passing, and that is that the solution in this answer requires at least version 8.0.  If you are using an earlier version of MySQL, either upgrade, or accept the fact that avoiding subqueries is most likely impossible in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
select name, group_concat(val) as dup_vals
from (
    select name, val, count(1) over (partition by val) as nr
    from t
) as u
where nr > 1
group by name
;
```

The inner select filters all occurrences of val that does not exists more than once. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=472d733daf129889159cbb95f1dbaa45).

For future posts, please include information that makes it possible to reproduce the problem (for example as a db<>fiddle). It is not particularly fun transforming ASCII-art tables into something useful

Comment: I don't know why I thought the goal was to get only the values present for all the names. If a value occurs more than once, it's already a duplicate of course, so the simple approach you took makes perfect sense. It looks like I was overthinking this.

Comment: @AndriyM, there are several interpretations possible. It is not easy to tell which one the op meant. So you could very well be correct with your answer.

Answer (score -2):

`Listagg` function should work for your requirement

```
select name, listagg(value,',') within group(order by value) as result
from table group by name;
```

Comment: Listagg is the standard function for string aggregation, but I dont think MYSQL implements it. GROUP_Concat seems to have similar funtionality as LISTAGG

Comment: I assume this is part of the reason for your downvotes, but its hard to tell without an explanation from those that downvoted